# Unable to open my excelSheet in MS-Excel iOS app from my iOS app via url scheme

Tags: ios, excel, url-scheme

Actually I am following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn911482.aspx) document to open my excel sheet in iOS MS_EXCEL app from my app via url scheme.
By using its documentation I open EXCEL app successfully. But I am totally unable to open my excel sheet . Every time EXCEL app gives me error showing in this image

[image]

I am passing my saved file url to Excel app. I have checked the saved file path by iExplorer. That file is perfectly opened . But in Excel app, its really giving me headache.

Please help me out that where am I making Mistake.
Here my code snippet

```
static NSString * encodeByAddingPercentEscapes(NSString *input) {
NSString *encodedValue =
(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                    kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                    (CFStringRef)input,
                                                    NULL,
                                                    (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                    kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
return encodedValue;
```

}

```
 -(NSURL*)excelUrlStringForFile:(NSString*)urlFile WithContext:(NSString*)strContext
 {
NSURL *result =[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ms-excel:ofe|u|%@|p|%@|c|%@",encodeByAddingPercentEscapes(urlFile),urlScheme,strContext] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:4]];
return result;
}
```

Here If I am not using 'encoding  string by `NSUTF8StringEncoding`'
this above `NSURL` object `result` is set to nil. So I must have to use encoding.

```
 NSURL *openExcelURL = [self excelUrlStringForFile:filePath WithContext:str_fileName];
        if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:openExcelURL])
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:openExcelURL];
}
```

Comment: Naaaah.. No luck.. I got another and temporary way.. UIDocumentIntractionController

Comment: Here is what I read from the comments of [this post](http://blog.beecomedigital.com/2015/02/16/opening-a-document-with-office-mobile-from-your-own-application/): `Due to the security model of iOS applications, it’s not possible to directly open a local file from an application to another application.`

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same situation, I'm trying to open local files from other application, looking into the website where you have seen the excel URL Scheme I found this text. It looks like you cannot open local files using this method, it is very strange but only it makes reference to OneDrive and SharePoint files... =S

If someone knows something about this issue would be very useful to us

> You can enable users who are running Office on an iOS device to open and edit files stored in SharePoint or OneDrive from any application, and then quickly return them to the original application when they’re done editing the file. To do this, you pass files to Office via protocol handlers, and you make sure that Office is invoked in a way that Office can understand.

Comment: I tried every way to get it done in this way. But didnt taste the victory. So now in temporary manner I had to use UIDocumentInteractionController for opening my file in excel.